# Red5 Service Fails to Start on Win 10 - Incorrect Function

Tags: red5

I installed Red5.  Service installed ok, but when I manually try to start it, I get the following error in my Windows Event Log:

"The Red5 Media Server service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
Incorrect function"

In the commons-daemon.log, I see the following:

- [2017-05-17 20:36:54] [info]  [11044] Starting service...
- [2017-05-17 20:36:54] [error] [11044] Failed creating java
- [2017-05-17 20:36:54] [error] [11044] ServiceStart returned 1
- [2017-05-17 20:36:54] [info]  [13816] Run service finished.
- [2017-05-17 20:36:54] [info]  [13816] Commons Daemon procrun finished

Event ID was 7024. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on Windows Server 2012 R2. Solution was to install the latest release of the Java SE Development Kit. In my case I just installed Java SE DK 8U144: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-windows-x64.exe

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by setting up the rtmp:// url correctly.  I did not enter in a stream name, as I thought the name parameter above the rtmp text box would do it for me.

It works, but it seems that the chip in my Note 5 just doesn't have the cpu power to stream smoothly, although I will admit I have only spent about 20 minutes trying to tune settings for best performance on my Sprint cell service.

Thank you for your quick reply.